# ActiveRecord having count query condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models : `Conversation` and `Message`
I need to retrieve all conversations that belongs to a `Brand` and where there are at least one message from the brand and one message from an influencer

This is my query :

```
Conversation.includes(:messages)
            .joins(:messages)
            .group("conversations.id, messages.id")
            .where("conversations.brand_id = ?", brand_id)           
            .having("COUNT(messages.authorable_type = 'Influencer') > 0 AND COUNT(messages.authorable_type = 'BrandMember') > 0")
            .limit(10)
```

But i get conversations that doesn't have messages from both... What am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: Can you share snippets of the relationships in the models?

Comment: Someone solved my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lays in `COUNT` expressions.

Note that `COUNT` counts all **NON-NULL** values. In your case you put to `COUNT` some conditional expression which evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` which are not `NULL`.

Laziest solution would be look like this:

```
COUNT(messages.authorable_type = 'Influencer' OR NULL)
```